# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value

Tags: c#, sql, parameters, error-handling, type-conversion

When I try to run this, it gives me the following error message:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'category_id' to data type int.

Here's my SQL and parameter code, I supposed it should work, but it doesn't.

```
mycmd.CommandText="SELECT * FROM categories WHERE @db_property = @property_id"; 

// This contains a string "category_id", which is correct.
mycmd.Parameters.Add("@db_property", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value=db_property_field; 

// This contains an Int, referring to the category_id in database. As of now, this is 1
mycmd.Parameters.Add("@property_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value=property_id;
```

After I'm going through this code, I run it through a Reader, and that's where I get the error message above. Been asking teacher, and excellent students in my class, no one can find a clue on, where the problem is.

Comment: Well, it's trying to convert the literal string `category_id` to an integer value, which of course fails. Can you post the relevant code with the line where the actual error occurs?

Comment: It occurs when it runs the line of my reader execution.

Comment: Does db_property_field contain "1"?

Comment: It's not trying to convert `1` to an `int`, but the _value_ `category_id` (as a varchar). I think Denys' answer should solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't add field name as parameter. Try to change your script to include actual field id:

```
mycmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE category_id = @property_id";
mycmd.Parameters.Add("@property_id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = property_id;
```

Comment: What im trying to do, is making a flexible way, of doing SQL querys, instead of should make a new Query every time, i want to SELECT something from my Database. That's why i uses field names as parameters, which should in theory work.

Comment: Correct. The first parameter is parsed as a literal string.

Comment: @KevinJensenPetersen Try to enclose the field name in square brackets (`[FieldName]`), that may work.

Comment: The first parameter is a string yes, that i pass through into the Query for testing in my WHERE. How should i solve it?

Comment: I don't know could this fit your needs but you can try to String.Format your firld names in 'where' clause and parameters for actual values. This would keep you from making new query for each case.

Comment: I see.. I'll go with your way then. Thanks!

Comment: Don't try to revent the wheel creating a query is required to select something in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your structure, but try the following:

```
mycmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM categories WHERE Cast(@db_property as Int) = @property_id";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is matching the two variables you are passing in so it will either return all the data or none of it! On top of that you are matching a char variable with an int. SQL will try to cast the char variable to an int.

```
@db_property = @property_id
```

should your query look like this?

```
SELECT * FROM categories WHERE db_property = @db_property AND property_id = @property_id
```

Comment: What my actually plan for the query, was for it to look like .. WHERE 'category_id' = 1

Answer (score 0):

If you look at your statement you are comparing the two parameters.  The WHERE clause is not on a table column ("categories") and the two parameters you are passing are different data types.  VarChar and Int.  When that command is executed the SQL engine is trying to compare two variables of different data types.

If you run the following SQL statements straight against SQL you will receive the same error.

```
DECLARE @Var1 VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @Var2 INT

SELECT @Var1 = 'Test', @Var2 = 1

SELECT * FROM dbo.categories  WHERE @Var1 = @Var2
```

Answer (score -1):

You can get solution from the following address:

http://net-informations.com/csprj/data-providers/cs-procedure-parameter.htm

For your information I Just reshape the code and use it to my needs.

Code of Stored Procedure is as follow:

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[PmSPValidate]
@a varchar(10)

AS
BEGIN
(SELECT AcctDsc,AcctAge 
FROM dbo.tblCoa 
WHERE AcctNo >= @a)

END

Code of C# :

 private void btnThirdTrial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connetionString = null;
            SqlConnection connection;
            SqlDataAdapter adapter;
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            SqlParameter param;
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            int i = 0;

            connetionString = "Data Source=FIN03;Initial Catalog=CmsTest;Integrated Security=True";

            connection = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

            connection.Open();
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "dbo.PmSPValidate";

            param = new SqlParameter("@a",Account.Text.ToString ());
            param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
            param.DbType = DbType.String;
            command.Parameters.Add(param);

            adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            adapter.Fill(ds);

            for (i = 0; i <= ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(" Name " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString() + "  Age " + ds.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString());

            }

            connection.Close();

        }
```